# SQLite Query in Android Application

Tags: android, sqlite

I need a sample code to fetch data from sqlite in android application.

1. based on user id i need to display data in textview.

eg. if i give Id:1

i need to display the corresponding values in textview below.

Pls Help me with the code

Thanks in advance

Raghav Raajagopalan

Comment: There are [so many posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Using+database+in+Android) there.

Comment: Try harder. What code do you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String SQL = "SELECT [spalte] FROM [tabelle] WHERE [spalte] = [wert];
Cursor c = sqldriver.ExecQuery(SQL);
if(c != null){
 if(c.getCount() > 0){
 c.moveToFirst();
 TextView.setText(c.getString(0));
 }                  
}
c.close();
c=null;
```

...

```
public static Cursor ExecQuery(String SQL) {
    Cursor c = null;
    try{
        c = myDB.rawQuery(SQL, null);
    }catch(SQLException e){
       GlobalVars.LastError = e.getMessage();
    }
    return c;
}
```